# How can I optimize big IntMap generation?

Tags: haskell

The below code's `allCases` is 2^20 size `IntMap` and its generation takes heavy computation and memory. I don't know whether this is inevitable cost, and how can I find out the spot making inefficiency.

```
import Control.Monad (forM_)
import Control.Monad.ST
import Data.Array
import Data.Array.ST
import Data.Bits
import Data.List
import qualified Data.IntMap as M

type Switch = Int
type Clock = Int

switches :: Array Switch [Clock]
switches = listArray (0, 9) [
  [0, 1, 2],
  [3, 7, 9, 11],
  [4, 10, 14, 15],
  [0, 4, 5, 6, 7],
  [6, 7, 8, 10, 12],
  [0, 2, 14, 15],
  [3, 14, 15],
  [4, 5, 7, 1, 15],
  [1, 2, 3, 4, 5],
  [3, 4, 5, 9, 13]]

type Quads = Int

intsToQuads :: [Int] -> Quads
intsToQuads [] = 0
intsToQuads (x:xs) = x .|. (intsToQuads xs `shiftL` 2)

switchCases :: [[Int]]
switchCases = sequence $ replicate 10 [0..3]

applySwitch :: Int -> STUArray s Int Int -> ST s ()
applySwitch sw clocks = forM_ (switches ! sw) $ \ix -> do
  clock <- readArray clocks ix
  writeArray clocks ix ((clock + 1) `rem` 4)

allCasesST :: Int -> STUArray s Int Int -> Int -> ST s (M.IntMap Int)
allCasesST ix clocks pushs
  | ix > 9 = do
    cs <- getElems clocks
    return (M.singleton (intsToQuads cs) pushs)
  | otherwise = do
    rs <- mapM next [pushs..pushs + 3]
    return (M.unions rs)
  where
    next pu = do
      rs <- allCasesST (ix + 1) clocks pu
      applySwitch ix clocks
      return rs

allCases :: M.IntMap Int
allCases = runST $ do
  st <- newArray (0,15) 0
  allCasesST 0 st 0

main = do
  putStrLn . show $ M.lookup 0 allCases
  return ()
```

The following are profiling results.
[image: Profiling results 1]

```
  2,754,242,472 bytes allocated in the heap
  2,095,063,056 bytes copied during GC
    788,992,504 bytes maximum residency (23 sample(s))
      3,087,880 bytes maximum slop
            815 MB total memory in use (0 MB lost due to fragmentation)

                                    Tot time (elapsed)  Avg pause  Max pause
Gen  0      2618 colls,     0 par   10.859s  11.052s     0.0042s    1.1284s
Gen  1        23 colls,     0 par    0.000s   0.011s     0.0005s    0.0009s

INIT    time    0.000s  (  0.001s elapsed)
MUT     time    1.531s  (  3.622s elapsed)
GC      time    8.750s  (  8.916s elapsed)
RP      time    0.000s  (  0.000s elapsed)
PROF    time    2.109s  (  2.146s elapsed)
EXIT    time    0.047s  (  0.072s elapsed)
Total   time   12.438s  ( 12.612s elapsed)

%GC     time      70.4%  (70.7% elapsed)

Alloc rate    1,798,688,961 bytes per MUT second

Productivity  12.7% of total user, 12.3% of total elapsed
```

.prof file (with some modification for tidiness).

```
    Mon Dec 25 23:52 2017 Time and Allocation Profiling Report  (Final)

       a.exe +RTS -p -hc -xc -s -c -RTS

    total time  =        1.52 secs   (1518 ticks @ 1000 us, 1 processor)
    total alloc = 1,576,087,408 bytes  (excludes profiling overheads)

COST CENTRE     MODULE       SRC                       %time %alloc

intsToQuads     Main         Main.hs:38:29-42          24.9   17.0
allCasesST      Main         Main.hs:55:13-23          13.7   20.2
applySwitch     Main         Main.hs:44:25-45          12.2    0.0
allCasesST      Main         Main.hs:51:11-25          10.5   44.2
applySwitch     Main         Main.hs:46:3-44            9.5    0.0
intsToQuads     Main         Main.hs:38:22-54           7.2    0.0
allCasesST.next Main         Main.hs:58:13-41           6.2    5.7
intsToQuads     Main         Main.hs:38:29-53           4.2    0.0
applySwitch     Main         Main.hs:45:12-30           2.6    7.1
allCasesST.next Main         Main.hs:59:7-27            2.2    0.0
allCasesST      Main         Main.hs:52:26-39           1.8    1.1
applySwitch     Main         Main.hs:(44,25)-(46,44)    1.5    0.0
allCasesST      Main         Main.hs:52:13-46           1.4    2.7
allCasesST      Main         Main.hs:54:11-38           0.7    2.1


                                                          individual     inherited
COST CENTRE           SRC                       entries  %time %alloc   %time %alloc

MAIN                  <built-in>                   0      0.1    0.0    100.0  100.0
 CAF                  GHC.IO.Encoding.CodePage     0      0.0    0.0      0.0    0.0
 CAF                  GHC.IO.Encoding              0      0.0    0.0      0.0    0.0
 CAF                  GHC.IO.Handle.Text           0      0.0    0.0      0.0    0.0
 CAF                  GHC.Show                     0      0.0    0.0      0.0    0.0
 CAF                  GHC.IO.Handle.FD             0      0.0    0.0      0.0    0.0
 CAF                  <entire-module>              0      0.0    0.0     99.9  100.0
  allCases            Main.hs:(63,12)-(65,19)      0      0.0    0.0     99.9  100.0
   allCases           Main.hs:64:9-25              0      0.0    0.0      0.0    0.0
   allCasesST         Main.hs:55:5-24              0      0.0    0.0      5.5    5.3
    allCasesST        Main.hs:55:13-23             0      5.5    5.3      5.5    5.3
   allCasesST         Main.hs:54:11-38             0      0.7    2.1     94.5   94.7
    allCasesST.next   Main.hs:59:7-27              0      0.1    0.0      0.5    0.0
     applySwitch      Main.hs:(44,25)-(46,44)      0      0.0    0.0      0.3    0.0
      applySwitch     Main.hs:44:25-45             0      0.1    0.0      0.3    0.0
       applySwitch    Main.hs:45:12-30             0      0.0    0.0      0.0    0.0
       applySwitch    Main.hs:44:32-44             0      0.2    0.0      0.2    0.0
    allCasesST.next   Main.hs:58:13-41             0      6.2    5.7     93.3   92.5
     allCasesST       Main.hs:52:5-47              0      0.1    0.0     39.7   20.8
      allCasesST      Main.hs:52:13-46             0      1.4    2.7     39.6   20.8
       allCasesST     Main.hs:52:26-39             0      1.8    1.1     38.2   18.1
        intsToQuads   Main.hs:38:22-54             0      7.2    0.0     36.4   17.0
         intsToQuads  Main.hs:38:29-53             0      4.2    0.0     29.1   17.0
          intsToQuads Main.hs:38:29-42             0     24.9   17.0     24.9   17.0
     allCasesST       Main.hs:55:5-24              0      0.1    0.0      8.3   14.9
      allCasesST      Main.hs:55:13-23             0      8.2   14.9      8.2   14.9
     allCasesST       Main.hs:51:11-25             0     10.5   44.2     10.5   44.2
     allCasesST.next  Main.hs:59:7-27              0      2.1    0.0     28.7    7.1
      applySwitch     Main.hs:(44,25)-(46,44)      0      1.5    0.0     26.5    7.1
       applySwitch    Main.hs:44:25-45             0     12.1    0.0     25.0    7.1
        applySwitch   Main.hs:46:3-44              0      9.5    0.0     10.4    0.0
         applySwitch  Main.hs:46:25-43             0      0.9    0.0      0.9    0.0
        applySwitch   Main.hs:45:12-30             0      2.6    7.1      2.6    7.1
  main                Main.hs:68:3-39              0      0.0    0.0      0.0    0.0
   main               Main.hs:68:21-39             0      0.0    0.0      0.0    0.0
   main               Main.hs:68:3-17              0      0.0    0.0      0.0    0.0
  switches            Main.hs:(22,12)-(32,19)      0      0.0    0.0      0.0    0.0
 main                 Main.hs:68:3-39              0      0.0    0.0      0.0    0.0
  main                Main.hs:68:3-17              0      0.0    0.0      0.0    0.0
```

Comment: Good question, but can you add a description of the algorithm? It's hard to differentiate 'inefficiency' from 'inevitable cost' when you don't know what the code should be doing. Some broad observations: `intsToQuads` takes 25% of time and 17% of alloc - but it looks like that function should run in constant memory; `44:25-45` allocates almost nothing - it's a very tight loop (very good!); `55:13-23` and `51:11-25` collectively allocated 60% of your programs memory - this is your first avenue of attack (since your program spends 70% time on GC, which isn't terrible nor good)

Comment: Also, many of your cost centres are named the same thing (these are autogenerated by GHC) which can make debugging confusing. Solely for readability, it may be useful to either manually add cost centres (and give them descriptive names) or to split your functions into many more functions (which would make the autogenerated names of GHC slightly more unique).

Comment: Some GC cost is inevitable when building large structures. You may be able to reduce it by increasing the initial heap size.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your algorithm is a bit too lazy, you are putting unevaluated thunks in your map.

Your original code performed as such:

```
<<ghc: 1185249008 bytes, 1136 GCs, 85006914/288126544 avg/max bytes residency (10 samples), 827M in use, 0.000 INIT (0.002 elapsed), 0.595 MUT (0.605 elapsed), 1.830 GC (2.065 elapsed) :ghc>>
./jeiea +RTS -tstderr  2.43s user 0.32s system 99% cpu 2.773 total
```

That is, 288MB residency, 2.4 seconds.

But if we force the evaluation of intsToQuads:

```
allCasesST :: Int -> STUArray s Int Int -> Int -> ST s (M.IntMap Int)
allCasesST ix clocks pushs
  | ix > 9 = do
    cs <- getElems clocks
    let n = intsToQuads cs
    n `seq` return (M.singleton n pushs)
```

Then the the performance is:

```
<<ghc: 1151694576 bytes, 1104 GCs, 26972457/72834536 avg/max bytes residency (11 samples), 215M in use, 0.000 INIT (0.002 elapsed), 0.500 MUT (0.515 elapsed), 0.735 GC (0.816 elapsed) :ghc>>
./jeiea +RTS -tstderr  1.24s user 0.11s system 98% cpu 1.367 total
```

Which is 72MB max residency and 1.25 seconds.

If we apply the same modification to `applySwitch` and `next` we get performance of:

```
<<ghc: 1151694576 bytes, 1104 GCs, 26972457/72834536 avg/max bytes residency (11 samples), 215M in use, 0.000 INIT (0.002 elapsed), 0.389 MUT (0.395 elapsed), 0.517 GC (0.573 elapsed) :ghc>>
```

Which is 72MB residency and about 1 second but the variance is huge.

EDIT:

The full code and run:

```
import Control.Monad (forM_)
import Control.Monad.ST
import Data.Array
import Data.Array.ST
import Data.Bits
import Data.List
import qualified Data.IntMap as M

type Switch = Int
type Clock = Int

switches :: Array Switch [Clock]
switches = listArray (0, 9) [
  [0, 1, 2],
  [3, 7, 9, 11],
  [4, 10, 14, 15],
  [0, 4, 5, 6, 7],
  [6, 7, 8, 10, 12],
  [0, 2, 14, 15],
  [3, 14, 15],
  [4, 5, 7, 1, 15],
  [1, 2, 3, 4, 5],
  [3, 4, 5, 9, 13]]

type Quads = Int

intsToQuads :: [Int] -> Quads
intsToQuads [] = 0
intsToQuads (x:xs) = x .|. (intsToQuads xs `shiftL` 2)

switchCases :: [[Int]]
switchCases = sequence $ replicate 10 [0..3]

applySwitch :: Int -> STUArray s Int Int -> ST s ()
applySwitch sw clocks = forM_ (switches ! sw) $ \ix -> do
  clock <- readArray clocks ix
  let n = ((clock + 1) `rem` 4)
  n `seq` writeArray clocks ix n

allCasesST :: Int -> STUArray s Int Int -> Int -> ST s (M.IntMap Int)
allCasesST ix clocks pushs
  | ix > 9 = do
    cs <- getElems clocks
    let n = intsToQuads cs
    n `seq` return (M.singleton n pushs)
  | otherwise = do
    rs <- mapM next [pushs..pushs + 3]
    return (M.unions rs)
  where
    next pu = do
      let n = ix + 1
      rs <- n `seq` allCasesST n clocks pu
      applySwitch ix clocks
      return rs

allCases :: M.IntMap Int
allCases = runST $ do
  st <- newArray (0,15) 0
  allCasesST 0 st 0

main = do
  putStrLn . show $ M.lookup 0 allCases
  return ()
```

With:

```
% time ./jeiea +RTS -tstderr
Just 0
<<ghc: 1151694576 bytes, 1104 GCs, 26972457/72834536 avg/max bytes residency (11 samples), 215M in use, 0.000 INIT (0.005 elapsed), 0.812 MUT (0.820 elapsed), 0.979 GC (1.093 elapsed) :ghc>>
./jeiea +RTS -tstderr  1.79s user 0.16s system 99% cpu 1.971 total
```

Comment: I could reach same max residency but not performance time, maybe due to my misapplication of your guide. Could you give me the full modified code?

Comment: Using `ghc -fforce-recomp -O2`?  Remember performance without `O2` makes baby Knuth cry.

Comment: Still same. I was already applying `-O2`. It takes about 1.3sec.

Comment: Ah, my claim of 0.39 seconds was looking at the mutator only (look at the quoted output) and omitted GC.  We should be able to get better efficiency and thus better performance by finding why GC is taking so long if desired.

Comment: `intsToQuads` looks like a pretty bad design (not tail recursive, for example), and I don't feel confident it is doing... whatever you'd want it to do.